# _x00D_ showing in Excel by using EPPlus library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I am using EPPlus 3.0 (codeplex latest library) library for download excel file. Everything working fine but some columns showing with **`"_x00D_"`** string on data. I researched in google, everybody saying it is newline character. I tried all scenarios still doesn't work.

Please advice me.

```
  Using pck As New ExcelPackage()
                    'Create the worksheets
   Dim wsAll As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("All")
   Dim wsManufacturing As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Manufacturing")
   Dim wsHealthcare As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Healthcare")
   Dim wsManagement As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Management")
   Dim wsSelling As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Selling")

   'Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
   wsAll.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtAllDownload, True)
   If dtManufacturing.Rows.Count > 0 Then
     wsManufacturing.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManufacturing, True)
   End If
   If dtChinaHealthcare.Rows.Count > 0 Then
     wsHealthcare.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtHealthcare, True)
   End If
   If dtChinaManagement.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       wsManagement.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManagement, True)
   End If
   If dtSelling.Rows.Count > 0 Then
      wsSelling.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtSelling, True)
   End If

   Dim filename As String = "FullExtract_" & Now.Year.ToString & Now.Month.ToString & Now.Day.ToString & ".xlsx"
    Dim fileBytes As [Byte]() = pck.GetAsByteArray()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.[Private])
    HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "private"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString())
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "60")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" & filename)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
```

Comment: are you sure that this data doesn't came from DataTables ?

Comment: well that would be first thing that I would look

Comment: if DataTable has this? How to replace with emptystring? I am directly loading from the table like wsManufacturing.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManufacturing, True)

Comment: well I would search all fields for "_x00D_" string, don't understand what are this underscores so I presume that you are really having that string somewhere in data

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this string came from DataTable, you can replace that with this method :

```
public static void Replace_x00D_(DataTable data)
{
  List<DataColumn> stringColumns = new List<DataColumn>();
  foreach (DataColumn dc in data.Columns)
  {
    if (dc.DataType == typeof(string))
      stringColumns.Add(dc);
  }

  foreach (DataRow rw in data.Rows)
  {
    foreach (DataColumn dc in stringColumns)
      rw.Field<string>(dc).Replace("_x00D_", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: search all fields for "x00D" string in datatable. I dont find anything in datatable. Saw spaces in datatable

Comment: what is the type of the column that produces this garbage ?

Comment: In database table columns defined in nvarchar(200)

Comment: well, it's hard to tell, could you paste value from offending row ?